# Material Dialog afterOpened vs AfterViewInit. Is it safe to accesss dialog data in AfterViewInit?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I open dialog in a standard way:

```
this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, {
      width: '90vw',
      height: '85vh',
      ....
```

And in DialogComponent I access dialog data in ngAfterViewInit:

```
  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData,
  ) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.data = this.data.width
```

(this is a pseudo code). As you see I dont use:

```
this.dialogRef.afterOpen().pipe( ...
```

Can anyone explain whats the difference between `this.dialogRef.afterOpen` and `ngAfterViewInit`?

Is it safe to access `data` in **AfterViewInit**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngAfterViewInit` is an Angular hook used to perform functions after a certain moment of the life of that instance of the component, [see here for more information](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).

`MatDialogRef.afterOpened` is an observable notified when the given instance of `MatDialog` is opened.

Basically, `ngAfterViewInit` should be used from inside the dialog to perform things after its view has been initialized, `MatDialogRef.afterOpened` should be used by the component that opens the dialog to perform things when the dialog has opened but has not yet been closed.

Since your data are injected in the constructor, they are already there during view initialization so it is safe to use them during that phase.

Comment: I could swear I saw `this.dialogRef.afterOpen()` within the dialog component itself somewhere in the docs. But cant find it now :D So that got me confused...

Comment: I'm late to this thread but if you not always open modals as components but mostly open modals from a templateRef your lifecycle hooks are from the current component, which will open many template dialogs upon user interaction so the all the lifecycle hooks already run. In this case the method that opens the modal from a templateRef is a good place to subscribe to this observable

Answer (score 1):

After reading the source code of DialogComponent [See Details](https://github.com/angular/components/tree/master/src/material/dialog)

this.dialogRef.afterOpen will trigger on the animation complete of the component.

where as ngAfterViewInit

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-lifecycle-hook',
   template: `
     <h3>Lifecycle Hook Demo</h3>
    `
})
export class LifecycleHookComponent { 
  constructor() {
    console.log("---constructor---");
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("---Inside ngOnInit---");
  }
  ngDoCheck() {
    console.log("---Inside ngDoCheck---");
  }
  ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log("---Inside ngAfterContentInit---");
  }
  ngAfterContentChecked() {
    console.log("---Inside ngAfterContentChecked---");
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log("---Inside ngAfterViewInit---");
  }  
  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    console.log("---Inside ngAfterViewChecked---");    
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    console.log("---Inside ngOnDestroy---");      
  }
}
```

Output:

```
---constructor--- 
---Inside ngOnInit--- 
---Inside ngDoCheck---
---Inside ngAfterContentInit---
---Inside ngAfterContentChecked---
---Inside ngAfterViewInit---
---Inside ngAfterViewChecked---
```

So you can use either on NgOnInit or after you ngAfterViewInit will get the data

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer directly but it could help with usage of `afterOpened`. In your component class inject a dialog instance, then open the modal using the templateRef the same way you would use a component declared in your modules'  entryComponents array. A demo in StackBlitz is provided below.

```js
@ViewChild('widgetEditorModal') public widgetEditorModal: TemplateRef<any>;
private widgetEditorDialogRef: MatDialogRef<TemplateRef<any>>;

isModalOpen = false;

constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

openWidgetEditorDialog() {

  const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
  dialogConfig.role = 'dialog';
  dialogConfig.width = '720px';

  // widgetEditorModal is my modal templateRef
  this.widgetEditorDialogRef = this.dialog.open(this.widgetEditorModal, dialogConfig);

  this.widgetEditorDialogRef.afterOpened().subscribe(result => {
      this.isModalOpen = true;
      console.log('widgetEditorModal has been opened!');
  });

  this.widgetEditorDialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      this.isModalOpen = false;
      console.log('widgetEditorModal has been close!');
  });
}
```

And the template piece:

```html
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="openWidgetEditorDialog()">Open modal</button>

<ng-template #widgetEditorModal>
  <div class="mat-dialog-header border-bottom">
    <h3 class="mat-h3 mb-0">Widget settings</h3>
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxLayoutGap="12px">
      <button mat-icon-button matDialogClose tabindex="-1">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Close dialog">close</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <mat-dialog-content>
    <div class="py-5">Your settings form here</div>
  </mat-dialog-content>
  <mat-dialog-actions class="border-top">
    <button type="button" mat-button matDialogClose>Cancel</button>
    <button type="button" mat-raised-button color="accent">Save changes</button>
  </mat-dialog-actions>
</ng-template>
```

[StackBlitz demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-modal-open-close?file=src/app/app.component.ts)